# Find the limit of the sequence $y_n$ defined by $x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence is defined as : $y_0 = x_0$ and $y_n = x_n - \alpha x_{n-1}$ where $ -1 \lt \alpha \lt 1 $

Also $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{y_n}=b $

Find $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {x_n}$

In my book there is a hint that says :

$x_1 = y_1 + \alpha y_0$

$x_2 = y_2 + \alpha y_1 + \alpha^2 y_0$

And so on till : $ x_n =y_n + \alpha y_{n-1} + \alpha^2 y_{n-2} + ... + \alpha^n y_0 $

Then it states that from last equality is :

$ \frac{b}{1-\alpha} = b + \alpha b + ... \alpha^n b + \frac{b \alpha^{n+1}}{1 - \alpha}$

First I would like to help me understand how it came to that last equality and maybe possible hints afterwards how to solve the limit.

Thank you

Comment: according to the first hint - shouldn't the definition of $y_n$ be $y_n=x_n-\alpha x_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Fixed now..

Comment: and if by last equality you mean $\frac{b}{1-\alpha}=...$, that is just a sum of geometric series multiplied by $b$

Comment: Yeah, but why $ \frac{b}{1 - \alpha}$ ?

Comment: first forget the $b$. than you get $1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\dots=\frac{1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}$. which corresponds well with the know formula for sum of geometric series: $$\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$
I believe the $b$ should be somehow helpful to make it more similar to the formula above

Comment: I got it now, it used limit on $\alpha$ . I was missing that. Thank you

Comment: I think that what you need to do next is prove, that you can put all $y$s equal to $b$. But I'm not sure

Comment: Is it the same as proving that $x_n -> \frac{b}{1 - \alpha} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: If $y_n = b$ for all $n$, then

$$\begin{split}
x_n  &= y_n + \alpha y_{n-1} + \alpha^2 y_{n-2} + \cdots + \alpha^n y_0 \\
&= b + \alpha b + \alpha^2 b+ \cdots + \alpha^n b \\
&= b(1+\alpha + \alpha^2+\cdots + \alpha^n) \\
&= \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha}.
\end{split}$$

Since $-1<\alpha<1$, $\alpha^{n+1} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, this implies

$$\tag{1} \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \frac{b}{1-\alpha}.$$

Of course this is not true in general that $y_n = b$. But we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n = b$$

we hope that in general $(1)$ still holds. With that in mind, consider

$$\begin{split}
\left| x_n - \frac{b}{1-\alpha}\right| &= \left|x_n - \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha} + \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha} - \frac{b}{1-\alpha} \right| \\
&\le \left|x_n - \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha}\right| + \left| \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha} - \frac{b}{1-\alpha} \right| \\
&= \left|x_n - \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha}\right| + \left| \frac{b}{1-\alpha}\right| |\alpha^{n+1}|. 
\end{split}$$

Note that the second term on the right goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. For the first term, consider

$$\begin{split}
x_n - \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha} &= y_n + \alpha y_{n-1} + \alpha^2 y_{n-2} + \cdots + \alpha^n y_0 - b(1+ \alpha + \alpha^2 + \cdots + \alpha^n) \\
&= (y_n -b) + \alpha (y_{n-1} - b) + \alpha^2(y_{n-2} -b) + \cdots + \alpha^n (y_0 - b),
\end{split}$$

which implies that for all $n$,

$$\begin{split} \left| x_n - \frac{b(1-\alpha^{n+1})}{1-\alpha}\right| &\le  |y_n -b| + |\alpha | \cdot |y_{n-1} - b| + |\alpha|^2 \cdot |y_{n-2} -b| + \cdots + |\alpha| ^n |y_0 - b|\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha|^{n-k} |y_k  -b|
\end{split}$$

Note that $|y_n - b|$ is small when $n$ is large. In particular, for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $N_1\in \mathbb N$ so that 
$$|y_n - b|<\epsilon $$
whenever $n\ge N_1$.

So we have

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha|^{n-k}| y_k - b| &= \sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1} |\alpha|^{n-k}| y_k - b| + \sum_{k=N_1}^n |\alpha|^{n-k}| y_k - b| \\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1} |\alpha|^{n-k}| y_k - b| +\epsilon \sum_{k=N_1}^n |\alpha|^{n-k} \\
& =   \sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1} |\alpha|^{n-k}| y_k - b| + \epsilon \frac{1-|\alpha|^{n-N_1+1} }{1-|\alpha|} \\
&\le |\alpha|^{n-N_1+1} M + \epsilon \frac{1}{1-|\alpha|},
\end{split}$$

where $M$ depends only on $N_1$. Now we choose $N_2 >N_1+1$ so that

$$|\alpha|^{n-N_1+1} <\epsilon/M,\ \ |\alpha|^{n+1} <\epsilon $$

whenever $n\ge N_2$. So we have

$$\left| x_n - \frac{b}{1-\alpha}\right| \le \left( 1 + \frac{1}{1-|\alpha|} + \left| \frac{b}{1-\alpha}\right|\right) \epsilon$$

whenever $n\ge N_2$. Thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \frac{b}{1-\alpha}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Great work there. Amazed.
Do you mind suggesting me some books with such problems? Of course if you know any.