# Convergence of $x_n + \lambda x_{n - 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers, $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and suppose that $x_n + \lambda x_{n - 1}$ converges. Is it true that $x_n$ converges?

Of course the statement does not hold in this generality: if you take $\lambda = -1$, $x_n = \log(n)$, then $x_n - x_{n - 1} = \log(\frac{n}{n - 1}) \to 0$ but $x_n \to +\infty$. I am especially interested in the case $|\lambda| < 1$, $x_n \geq 0$, but solving the general problem would be even better. Any help?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1635341/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2935922/42969.

Comment: @MartinR perfect, thank you. I would still let the question open for $|\lambda| > 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|\lambda | < 1$ then the convergence of $(x_n + \lambda x_{n - 1})$ implies the convergence of $(x_n)$, see for example

- [Find the limit of the sequence $y_n$ defined by $x_{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635341/find-the-limit-of-the-sequence-y-n-defined-by-x-n)

If $|\lambda | \ge 1$ then this conclusion does not hold, a counterexample is $x_n = (-\lambda)^n$: The sequence  $(x_n)$ diverges, but $x_n + \lambda x_{n - 1} = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @avril_14th: You are welcome! – You might consider to *accept* the answer by clicking on the check mark, if it helped to solve your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: just did it, thanks for the information!